# ¿Como puedo imprimir con vue js una lista de 2018 a 1920?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

intento imprimir una lista con v-for que haga lo mismo que un ciclo for de esta manera

```
for(n=2018; n>=1920; n--)
```

Esto imprime una lista de 2018 a 1920

de la forma que lo tengo ahorita es

```
v-for="n in 2018)" v-if='n >= 120'
```

Pero obviamente la lista se imprime de 1920 a 2018

Comment: mmm.. podes mostrar la lista que estas tratando de imprimir? ese v-for no anda para nada no? el v-if para que lo queres?

Comment: el v-if es solo para que no imprima los numero mayores a 1919

Comment: ok. si no te sirvio la respuesta que te dieron, podrias mostrar como tenes la lista?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una propiedad computada que devuelva el arreglo de años en el orden que deseas.

#### Ejemplo

```js
window.onload = function() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#editor',
    data: {
      selected: ''
    },
    computed: {
      getYears: function() {
        let years = [];
        for (let n = 2018; n >= 1920; n--) {
          years.push(n);
        }
        return years;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in getYears" v-bind:value="option">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Seleccionado: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Referencias:

- [List Rendering > Displaying Filtered/Sorted Results](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results)
- [Form Input Bindings > Select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)